# Why was "Infamous" (2006) so titled?

Tags: title, infamous

Why was [*Infamous*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0420609/) (2006) so titled? (This seems to me a strange and even bad title.)

Does the title refer to anything? What or who is infamous?

(I think the starting sequence also had "famous", then "I famous", then "Infamous".)

Comment: It likely refers to the fact that the movie has various accounts of Capote's actions, as told by friends etc. Hence Capote is infamous.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Yes, my guess was along those lines too. I was hoping to get a more in-depth analysis here (but unfortunately so far I've gotten only an answer from someone who hasn't even watched the movie and simply quoted a one-sentence plot summary from IMDb).

Answer (score 2):

The description of the film on the linked IMDb page describes the plot thusly:

> While researching his novel "In Cold Blood", Truman Capote develops a close relationship with **convicted murderers** Dick Hickock and Perry Smith.

I think it's fair to assume that it's Hickock and Smith who are "Infamous".

Comment: Did you watch the movie? I did and I really don't think "Infamous" refers to them. The entire movie centers heavily on Capote.

Comment: Capote may be the main character, but that doesn't mean the film has to be named after him.

Comment: So your answer is just based solely on a guess based solely on what you read on IMDb?

Comment: I'd call it more of a deduction. If anyone in that movie could be considered "infamous", it's surely the men who murdered an entire family in cold blood.

Comment: @user24096 If you watched the whole movie and don’t understand the title, why do you think someone needs to watch the movie to understand the title? It could be that Capote also has some infamy about him, but primarily the title seems to refer to the murderer(s).

Comment: The murders were terrible.  Capote's book made the murders (and the murderers) infamous.  And probably made Capote infamous, too.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Watching the movie is necessary but not sufficient for answering the question (unless we have explicit quotes and commentary from directors/producers/actors/etc.). (The Stack Exchange network usually has answers from experts. So I would have thought that to be an expert about a movie requires at the very least watching the movie, though perhaps I am mistaken.)

Comment: @user24096 I am an expert on Windows servers but that doesn’t mean I’ve worked on *your* specific server. At the same time, I don’t have to log on to *your* server to have a good chance at knowing the answer to a question you might have about it. Also, Stacks like this one are a little different. Film interpretation cannot be nearly as objective as the topics of many other Stacks.